# Implementing Tagging and Excluding Filters with Solrj / Spring Data Solr

Tags: solr, solrj, spring-data-solr

I am trying to implement a Solr Facet search with multi-select on a field. To take this example: http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-LocalParametersforFaceting, I would like to generate this call to solr:

```
q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype
```

I am not sure how to call this using solrj (java) as I don't want to add a simple filed but I need to include the tagging and excluding (!tag=dt and !ex=dt). Any ideas what the java code should look like?

I am using Spring-Data-Solr which seems to be too basic to make such an advance call. So I think I need to go a level lower and use solrj. Either solution would be great (solrj or spring-data-solr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following block should create the querystring you want.

```java
SimpleFacetQuery query = new SimpleFacetQuery(new SimpleStringCriteria("mainquery"))
  .addFilterQuery(new SimpleQuery(new Criteria("status").is("public")))
  .addFilterQuery(new SimpleQuery(new Criteria("{!tag=dt}doctype").is("pdf")));
query.setFacetOptions(new FacetOptions("{!ex=dt}doctype"));

solrTemplate.queryForFacetPage(query, YourBean.class);
```

Comment: This works for the easy case that you don't want to provide any facet-specific options (f.<field>.facet.<option>). As soon as you try to use options for the facet, these won't work, because then, the Solr parameter "f.{!ex=dt}doctype.facet.limit" would be generated. And with "{!ex=dt}" this doesn't work, "f.doctype.facet.limit" would be needed.

Answer (score 2):

With [link](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolJava) I can do this :-

```
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.add("fq", "{!tag=dt}doctype:pdf");
params.add("facet.field", "{!ex=dt}doctype");
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SolrQuery` (which is a subclass of `ModifiableSolrParams` from the other answer):

```
solrQuery.addFilterQyery("{!tag=dt}doctype:pdf");
solrQuery.addFacetField("{!ex=dt}doctype");
```