# How to create tagged FacetRangeQuery with spring-data-solr?

Tags: spring-data-solr

With spring-data-solr 1.5.0 where range faceting is supported its hard to apply tagging.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#solr.misc.faceting.range

Please read below mentioned post for tagging when faceting is applied on simple fields.
[Implementing Tagging and Excluding Filters with Solrj / Spring Data Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897586/implementing-tagging-and-excluding-filters-with-solrj-spring-data-solr)

I want to ask how I can apply range faceting with exclude tags?

Comment: currently this isn't that easy, I opened a ticket therefore: [DATASOLR-259](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATASOLR-259)