# Tagging fields with Spring Data Solr

Tags: solrj, spring-data-solr

I'm using Spring Data Solr 4.0.5.RELEASE and can't find a way to properly tag fields in my filter query to achieve something like `{!tag=price}price:10`. There is a similar post here and an accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16903861/10225026, however this solution doesn't work when I use isNull() criteria like so `Criteria.where("{!tag=price}price").isNull()`. The query ends up being `-{!tag=price}price:[* TO *]` instead of `{!tag=price}-price:[* TO *]`.

For the same reason it's not possible to use FieldWithFacetParameters with parameters like `setMissing(true)` on fields with tags/keys/exclusions as spring data produces queries like `f.{!key=price ex=typeId,modelId,status}price.facet.missing=true` when it should be `f.price.facet.missing=true`.

Is there a proper way to add tags / keys and exclusions to query fields?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to add query tag for filter query:

```
SimpleQuery query = new SimpleFacetQuery();
....
query.addFilterQuery(new SimpleQuery(new Criteria("{!tag=price}-price").isNull()));
```

And for facet options:

```
SimpleFacetQuery query = new SimpleFacetQuery();
...
FacetOptions facetOptions = new FacetOptions();
facetOptions.addFacetOnField("{!key=price ex=typeId,modelId,status}price");

query.setFacetOptions(facetOptions);
```

To make facet options work also need to add the following into request handler default parameters in solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
....
<lst name="appends">
  <str name="f.price.facet.missing">true</str>
</lst>
....
```